# RichFaces - a4j:ajax is not being triggered when using two dynamic lists

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, jstl

The code with the error is as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:select defaultLabel="Seleccionar región" value="#{StaticInfo.regionElegida}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.regiones.entrySet()}" var="region" itemValue="#{region.key}" itemLabel="#{region.value}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="provs" listener="#{StaticInfo.updateProvincias}" />
    </rich:select>
    <rich:select id="provs" defaultLabel="Seleccionar provincia" value="#{StaticInfo.provinciaElegida}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{StaticInfo.provincias.entrySet()}" var="prov" itemValue="#{prov.key}" itemLabel="#{prov.value}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="texto" />
    </rich:select>
    <h:outputText value="#{StaticInfo.provinciaElegida)}" id="texto" />
</h:form>
```

The lists display the items correctly and the bean has the required getters and setters for `provinciaElegida`. Now, the second select's items will depend on what is selected on the first select. And for some reason the outputText element isn't displaying any results.

Thank you.

Comment: As expected, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Right now I just want to display the value of the second select, however apparently the fact the values are generated in run-time makes the second ajax call fail.

Comment: Ah, I know the outputText isn't doing that, but all I'm doing is debugging right now because the ajax call is not working. I'll fix the outputText to the correct code.

Comment: Ok, its for testing purposes. Make sure your managed bean is @ViewScoped. And don't print the keySet String, instead try to print `StaticInfo.provinciaElegida.algunAtributoTipoString`, and remember to make it work, the `<h:outputText>` must be outside the form, so the value will not update/modify your current `StaticInfo.provinciaElegida.algunAtributo` value.

Comment: It's request scoped, however the first ajax call works just fine.

Comment: When the ManagedBean is RequestScoped, it will be created for every request (even ajax requests!). If your managed bean must handle more than 1 request in the same view, it must have ViewScoped. That will make it work.

Comment: No hay problema. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so I don't leave the question unanswered...

The problem was that the bean was Request scoped. As Luiggi explained:

> When the ManagedBean is RequestScoped, it will be created for every
>   request (even ajax requests!). If your managed bean must handle more
>   than 1 request in the same view, it must have ViewScoped.

I was trying to submit several requests in one view, hence "resetting" the bean and effectively killing what it was supposed to do. When I changed the bean to @ViewScope, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<a4j:ajax event="change" render="texto" />`, you can try to use `<a4j:support/>`

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu"  value="#{Bean1.val1}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean1.selectItems}"/>
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{Bean1.onSelectOneMenuChange}" reRender="textbox1"   />
 </h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText id="textbox1" value="#{Bean1.textbox1}"> </h:inputText>
```

Comment: `<a4j:support>` is for RichFces 3.x. OP's using RichFaces 4.x, where support was replaced by `<a4j:ajax>` to follow the JSF 2 standard.